# What is the category to change the colors in the Error List window in the Visual Studio color theme editor

Tags: visual-studio, colors, themes, editor

I am trying to customize the colors of the "Error List" in Visual Studio using the Color Theme Editor extension but I cannot find the correct category to change the settings.

I have tried filtering by the keywords error, diag and list but don't see anything helpful and also searched through the Environment category.

I must be overlooking something.

Answer (score 0):

The forecolor is changed/influenced by Environment Category - CommandBarTextActive and the background is changed by the TreeView Category - BackGround

But CommandBarTextActive  also controls the forecolor on the main menu!